# Spin Control and Entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

I have a thought-experiment sort of question and I don't know where to start. Suppose you have an entangled pair, e1 and e2, and you split them. Then BEFORE reading them, you spin control e1 to +, then e2 would be -, correct?

Can you then, AFTER, reapply spin control to e1 and make it -. Would e2 then flip back to + also?

Comment: "Spin control" by forcing one into a particular spin breaks entanglement.  You can't force one into a particular state by acting on the other.

Answer (score 1):

Initially the pair is in state $(P\otimes M)+(M\otimes P)$.  (I am writing "P" and "M" instead of "+" and "-" so as not to confuse the state "plus" with the addition operation in the state space.)

You observe the first electron and happen to measure $P$.  Now the pair is in the state $P\otimes M$.  Note that this state is not entangled (i.e. it is a tensor product).  So at this point nothing you do to the first electron is going to affect measurements made on the second.

Comment: "You observe the first electron and happen to measure P."

I'm curious about this stage. Can you spin control it, thereby causing it to be P, and thus the other to be M?

Comment: @user1601118:  If you compute what happens when you apply a unitary transformation on the left, you'll see that it's impossible to convert the state to something of the form $P\otimes X$.  And indeed we know this even without the computation, because otherwise you could use this mechanism to transfer information faster than light.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm getting at. MIT has shown within the last six months that entanglement produces a wormhole between the [pairs](http://web.mit.edu/newsoffice/2013/you-cant-get-entangled-without-a-wormhole-1205.html), which wouldn't violate FTL information. So on a conceptual level I'm not so sure.

Do you have an experiment or a publication you can point me to? I'm not a physicist and am not sure where to start. My background is in math and computing. Thanks.

Comment: sorry I was writing this comment before your edit. How does spin control work then? Is it fundamentally not applicable to an electron in an entangled [state](http://nsf.gov/discoveries/disc_summ.jsp?cntn_id=116456&org=NSF)?

Comment: @user1601118:  I assume that by "spin control" you mean the application of a unitary operator.  If you're in the vicinity of the first electron, you can of course apply any unitary operator you want on the left.  This will bring the pair to $(\alpha P+\beta M)\otimes P+(\gamma P+\delta M)\otimes M$, where the Greek letters represent the elements of your matrix.  If you're trying to achieve a state of the form $P\otimes X$, you'll need $\beta=\delta=0$, contrary to the invertibility of your matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You will break an entanglement once you change the spin of one component independently.